# FillPath Union of Polygons in a Inclusive(non-XOR) Fashion

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, region, graphicspath

I need to fill a complex region with anti-aliasing.

The region is composed of numerous rotated rectangles (as of petal of a sunflower) and a central circle.

Region does not support anti-aliasing

so I tried FillPath but areas where rectangles overlap are not filled. (XOR'ed)

```
        // Has alpha so FillPath-ing multiple times doesn't help
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(128, 32, 64, 255);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
        Region region = null;
        //GraphicsPath bigPath = new GraphicsPath();
        for (int i = 0; i < nPetals; i++)
        {
            GraphicsPath pat = new GraphicsPath();
            Point p1, p2, p3, p4; // Actual code omitted
            pat.AddPolygon(new[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 });           
            //bigPath.AddPolygon(new[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 });
            if (region == null)
                region = new Region(pat);
            else region.Union(pat);
        }           
        var pathCirc = new GraphicsPath();
        pathCirc.AddEllipse(100,200,3,3);
        region.Union(path);     
        g.FillRegion(brush, region);    //Aliased
        //g.FillPath(brush, bigPath);   //XOR'ed
```

Is there any way to GraphicsPath.AddPolygon/AddEllipse() non-XOR way?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the [GraphicsPath.FillMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.fillmode)? Try `FillMode.Winding`. Note that the way to determine whether parts of a path need to be filled or not is a relatively complex algorithm that *may* sometimes appear weird, borderline incongruous, but that's a general *rule* in relation to Paths (the Framework is just applying it). -- Without the actual code, it's hard to say how to fix it if changing the `FillMode` is not enough: you have to build your Path keeping in mind its specific features.

Comment: FillMode.Winding should do the job. If not you could close the path figure after each rectangle.

Comment: FillMode.Winding works only on some degrees of rotation (of the rectangle). Even Winding mode doesn't work all-inclusive way.

Comment: Did you read the Remarks section of the [FillMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.fillmode) enumerator?

Comment: @Jimi Yeah I see what's going on there but that's really not about solving the problem, right? I'm just curious if there's any easier way than manually calculating outline and FillPath.

Comment: You have to fill Paths, not Regions. You did that? It's nowhere to be seen. The code you posted cannot be reproduced, since you're using undefined objects, as the `path` object in `region.Union(path);`. If you want concrete help with your code, you need to post the full code that can reproduce the exact problem: not pseudo-code, random pieces of code or invisible code.